# Dnamically modify NumericalScaleBase.Minimum and NumericalScaleBase.Maximum properties to always include 0 in x-axis

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I am modifying a bar series graph for a .NET reporting aplication done with Telerik and C#. I need the chart to always include 0 in the x-axis values as well as to adjust automatically to the data.

I have set NumericalScaleBase.Minimum as NaN and NumericalScaleBase.Maximum as NaN. This makes the chart adjust automatically to the data. The problem is, this configuration crops the chart for quite high or quite low values, and it doesn’t include 0 in the x-axis (see image below):

[image: The start position is set automatically as 200 instead of 0.]

If I set NumericalScaleBase.Minimum or NumericalScaleBase.Maximum properties to a fixed value, the graph area won't adapt to the values of the variables displayed and there could be cases where it would be dificult to read the information (when values of the variables are relatively small).

[image: Fixed values of máximum and mínimum may not be the best solution for all cases]

I am new in this environment and I am not finding alternative ways to solve it. Is there a way to adjust the chart automatically to the data but always include 0 in the x-axis?

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  Can't you set the minimum and maximum whenever the data changes, instead of fixed values?

Comment: I want to modify the minimum and maximum whenever the data changes, but always include 0 in the x-axis.

Comment: Is there any other clarification I can make?

Comment: I haven't find a way to do that.

Comment: As a short answer to @zer0 's question: no.